# When to use ValueObject vs record

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

When I design an API should I be using `record` or `ValueObject` for all of my DTO objects? If I need data to be immutable for my .NET Core Api how I can make a call what to use and when (record or ValueObject)?

For `record` as I understand I should follow the next scenario:

```
[HttpPost("login")]
public IActionResult Login(LoginRequest request)
{
    var authResult = _authenticationService.Login(request.Email, request.Password); //returns a data class
    var response = new AuthenticationResponse(
        authResult.Id,
        authResult.FirstName,
        authResult.LastName,
        authResult.Email,
        authResult.Token
        );
    return Ok(response);
}
```

Where **AuthenticationResponse**

```
public record AuthenticationResponse
(
    Guid Id,
    string FirstName,
    string LastName,
    string Email,
    string Token
);
```

**LoginRequest**

```
public record LoginRequest
(
    string Email,
    string Password
);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My general guidance is:

> A record is a fancy class. If you're not positive that you need a record, then use a class.

That being said, what are the characteristics of your type that you are looking for?

**Immutability**: DTO's that are immutable are generally thread-safe. Classes can be made immutable by using `get` only properties, or using the mutate once with `init`. Where records are by default mutate once, with `init` setters only.

**Value equality**: DTO's do not generally require value equality. Especially if the data itself contains an identifier.

You have a GUID identifier in your DTO, so a ValueObject or value equality is not likely needed in this example.

**Less typing**: I'm all for typing less, so in .NET 6 or .NET 7 I might have used a record anyways because of the primary constructor. Primary constructors have come to classes as well in .NET 8, making using a record to type less not as beneficial.

**Serialization**: Another use of DTOs is to serialize data. When you need to serialize data with something that requires a public parameter-less constructor such as `XmlSerializer` or `JSON.NET` do not use a record.

> Note: JSON.NET *prefers* the public parameter-less constructor, but can be configured with `JsonConstructorAttribute`, that being said trying to apply this attribute to the record mostly defeats the purpose IMO.

**Conclusion**: If this is targeting .NET 8, I would prefer a class for this specific example, and generally I always use a class unless I can justify using a different type like record, struct, record struct etc.

---

### Example: A DTO that needs to be serialized.

If the serializer requires a public parameter-less constructor, my DTO may look like this.

```cs
[Serializable]
public class AuthenticationResponse3()
{
    public Guid Id { get; init; } = Guid.Empty;
    public string FirstName { get; init; } = null!;
    public string LastName { get; init; } = null!;
    public string Email { get; init; } = null!;
    public string Token { get; init; } = null!;
}
```

### Example: I could have a DTO with a constructor.

```cs
internal sealed class AuthenticationResponse
{
    public AuthenticationResponse(Guid id, string firstName, string lastName, string email, string token)
    {
        Id = id;
        FirstName = firstName;
        LastName = lastName;
        Email = email;
        Token = token;
    }

    public Guid Id { get; }
    public string FirstName { get; }
    public string LastName { get; }
    public string Email { get; }
    public string Token { get; }
}
```

### Example: Same as above, but with C# 12 primary constructor

```cs
internal sealed class AuthenticationResponse5(Guid id, string firstName, string lastName, string email, string token)
{
    public Guid Id { get; } = id;
    public string FirstName { get; } = firstName;
    public string LastName { get; } = lastName;
    public string Email { get; } = email;
    public string Token { get; } = token;
}
```

Comment: Do you mean to use just classes as "contract" data models in API, but to make it immutable I should remove ```set``` and use parametrized constructor or have {get; init;} for my properties in DTOs?

Comment: you should do whichever of those makes your DTO immutable. That's a whole other topic.  You could use init-only, or get only properties, or if you have a constructor and fields you'll want to mark the fields as `readonly`.

Comment: @Jivopis updated with examples

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is use `record`s.

`ValueObject` is a concept and none of the concepts specific advantages are useful for you in this situation. A `record` is a default implementation of the ValueObject concept and you will never need more than that default for your API model classes. So it doesn't make any sense to use `ValueObject` when you don't need the options it gives you.